# My UINavBar doesn't Respond to Touch, and Scrolls with tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a subclass of a UITableViewController, and I want to add a UINavBar to it. It is a very similar setup to the native contacts app, where you tap "add contact", and it presents a grouped tableview with a navbar at the top with a "cancel," and "done" option. The key is that I need it to present using a vertical transition (effectively with presentModalViewController:animated:yes), but I have tried using Interface Builder and adding it programmatically, and in both cases, the buttons do not respond, and the bar scrolls with the tableview, rather than staying at the top.

Thanks in advance,

HBhargava

Comment: Posting your code would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're making the navigation bar a subview of the table view, that explains why the navigation bar scrolls with the table view.

Try this in the action method:

```
MyTableViewController *table = [MyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyledGrouped];
UINavigationController *nav = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:table];

[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Then in your table view controller's `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
```